# Candidate submission and placements SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

May I know what is the best way to create a table structure in SQL Server that would store large amount of data as well retrieve the data easily, taking performance into consideration.

For example:

1. Candidates to Jobs (one-to-many or many-to-one)
2. Candidates Submitted to Jobs (many-to-many)
3. Candidates Placed to Job (one-to-one)

I've got 2 tables with few columns - like this:

```
+-------------+    +------------+
| Candidates  |    |    Jobs    |
+-------------+    +------------+
| CandidateID |    | JobID      |
| DisplayName |    | JobTitle   |
| JobTitle    |    | UserID     |
| UserID      |    | CreateDate |
| CreateDate  |    +------------+
+-------------+
```

Now, I would like to create another table to store submissions and placements of Candidate(s) to Job(s).

Could someone give me few examples of how I can store this data.

Comment: The way you've suggested yourself sounds pretty suitable.

Comment: Thank you. 
1) I wanted to know the better way to create the 3rd or 4th table with foreign key constrains linking these 2 tables Candidates and Jobs & along with indexing these and show submissions and placements . 

2) I wanted to retrieve data in such a way to show all submissions and/or placements that are made in a year (date range). Here a candidate can have multiple submissions to different jobs OR multiple candidates could be submitted to a single job.

Well, I heard writing UNION could impact the performance when retrieving large set of data.